# How to change html output of method "getItemHtml" in custom theme

Tags: magento2, layout, template

I'm overriding the file **Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml**, I stumbled upon some php code generating html code which I can't find its origin

Here is the code

```
<?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $_item) :?>
   <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

So my goal is to change the html output of the function **getItemHtml**, the block handling the template is **@var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Grid**

I don't understand how does it works, I guess it's not hard coded and we can change a layout which handle this?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just looking for the file which holds the HTML for each item rendered in that foreach list?

You can find that here:

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml**

You can create a version of this in your theme for your custom HTML here:

**Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml**

Comment: Thanks, it was what I was looking for, what was your process finding it?

Comment: For speed when developing themes I install this: https://www.mgt-commerce.com/documentation/magento2-mgt-developer-toolbar This show all the blocks along with the paths to the HTML files used